# How to change launcher activity if We have to create second activity with custom adapter?

Tags: android, custom-adapter, android-launcher

I want to change my launcher activity.My first created activity has selecteable listview.When user"s open the application at first time;He will select persons then my second created activity that these selected persons come to my custom listview.My problem is ; How to change launcher activity because at my second activity has custom listview that if User dont click to any persons my second activity will be empty so that I get error message.How can I fix this ?

My first activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<String> selectedlistisim = new ArrayList<>();

    int girisyazısıcount = 2 ;
    ArrayList<String> listte = new ArrayList<String>();
    String phonenumber;
ArrayList<String> selectedlist = new ArrayList<>();
    ListView chosinglist;
Button kaydet ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      kaydet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.kaydet);
   chosinglist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.chosing);
        chosinglist.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

        getNumber(this.getContentResolver());


 }

    private void getNumber(ContentResolver contentResolver) {
        Cursor phones = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
        while (phones.moveToNext())
        {

            String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            phonenumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

            System.out.println(".................."+phonenumber);



            listte.add(phonenumber);
        }
        phones.close();// close cursor
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.checkrow,
                R.id.checkedTextView2,listte);


kaydet.setEnabled(false);
        chosinglist.setAdapter(adapter);
        chosinglist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String selecteditem = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();


                if (selectedlist.contains(selecteditem)){
                    selectedlist.remove(selecteditem);

                }else selectedlist.add(selecteditem);




                if (selectedlist.size() >= 5 && selectedlist.size() < 16 ) {


                    kaydet.setEnabled(true);
                }
                 if (selectedlist.size() == 16){
                     kaydet.setEnabled(false);

                 }
if (selectedlist.size() == 4){
    kaydet.setEnabled(false);
}


kaydet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AnaMenu.class);
i.putStringArrayListExtra("listem",selectedlist);
        startActivity(i);

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "abc.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        MainActivity.this.finish();
    }
});
            }
        });
    }


}
```

My second Activity :

```
public class AnaMenu extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final int MENU_Ara = Menu.FIRST + 1;
    OyunTextView oyunTextView;
    static final int AnketDegerlendirmesi = 1337;
   int selectedPosition ;
    String[] afteractivitydialogitems;
    int toplamaislemi;
    String[] dialogdegerleri;

    boolean[] dialogcheckeditems;

    String toast;

    TextView sayılar;
    ListView liste;

int a = 60 ;
    ArrayList<String> kullanıcısayıdegerlistesi = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayList<Integer> mUserselecteditems = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ana_menu);
        liste = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.oyun);
        //Adapter im.




        oyunTextView = new OyunTextView();

        liste.setAdapter(oyunTextView);

        registerForContextMenu(liste);

        afteractivitydialogitems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.anket);

        dialogcheckeditems = new boolean[afteractivitydialogitems.length];

        dialogdegerleri = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.anketdeğer);



//show the first activity when First time launched application. 
        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("MyAppPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean settingsFilled = prefs.getBoolean("SettingsFilled", false);

        if (!settingsFilled){
            Intent sa = new Intent(AnaMenu.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(sa);



            SharedPreferences pr = this.getSharedPreferences("MyAppPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("SettingsFilled", true);
            editor.commit();
        }




    }


    class OyunTextView extends BaseAdapter {


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            Intent i = getIntent();
            final ArrayList<String> secilmis = i.getStringArrayListExtra("listem");


            return secilmis.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.oyuntextview, null);
            TextView namesbox = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.isim);
            sayılar = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sayı);
            Intent i = getIntent();
            final ArrayList<String> secilmis = i.getStringArrayListExtra("listem");

            for (int defa = 0; defa < secilmis.size(); defa++) {
                kullanıcısayıdegerlistesi.add("50");
 //   if (kullanıcısayıdegerlistesi.contains("50")){sayılar.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.elli));}




            }
            namesbox.setText(secilmis.get(position));
            sayılar.setText(kullanıcısayıdegerlistesi.get(position));
                   sayılar.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.elli));
convertView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yüz));
            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

Comment: you want when you second activity is empty launch first activity?

Comment: @BrunoFerreira I think he doesn't want the second activity to launch if nothing got selected in his first activity

Comment: I want to launch second activity then I record all selected items to datebase.(Data base is not created now.)

Comment: So you want this? The user opens for the first time , selects the person and go to second activity in second activity you setore selected data in database. when user exists and launch app again go to the second activity directly and not the first. And if the user dont select nothing in first activity not opens the second activity.

Comment: yes,I want this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to fix the **empty list error** just try do this:

```
    kaydet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             if(selectedlist.size()>0){
                   Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AnaMenu.class);
                   i.putStringArrayListExtra("listem",selectedlist);
                   startActivity(i);

                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "abc.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               MainActivity.this.finish();
             }else{
               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No itens added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

              }
  }
    });
```

This **check** if **list** not have **itens** and if not show text, if yes go to the next **activity**.

For **open** the **second activity** instead of **first**, if user launchs activity for the second time do this logic, in **first activity** before super.oncreate() check if database has data if yes start **second activity**, if database is empty do nothing.

**Example of my logic**:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //here you check if database has data

        if(hasdata){
           //start second activity
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       //Or if you want you can put logic here is the same

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_loginactivity);

        //Not put here below setcontentview!!!!
    }
```

So **before** create the **activity** check if **database** has data and if yes go to other **activity**, because **activity** as not created and **layout** has not added, for user is the same as opens the second activity when click in launcher icon.

Comment: Ok. I am starting to create data base for loading to my second activity.But I have a question.I don"t understand, you said before super.oncreate().Do you mean use persistentState ?

Comment: Probably no I will update the answer with na exemple of what I´m thinking

Comment: Ok. When I finished to create database I am going to comment here.Thanks for helping

Comment: I have comleted my databee and your answer is true.Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

What Can help you the most is try to put following lines in Oncreate same as here.
This will check if the list is null and if yes than will redirect to list activity else continues.

```
 @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       //add some code to detect if parent is selected
       if (parent == null){
           Intent in = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, PersonAcrivity.class);
           startActivity(in);
       }
```